# Поиск по ключевым словам в Интернете

Tags: c#

Уважаемые! Задача стоит такая: нужно написать прогу на C# по поиску сайтов по ключевым словами, чтоб она атоматически выкачивала найденые страницы из нета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не стоит задача написать новый гугл :-), то нужно обращаться к какому-нибудь поисковику, передавая в качестве параметра ключевые слова для поиска и анализировать ответ. Т.е. парсить HTML и извлекать адреса найденных страниц. И после этого скачивать найденные страницы.

Comment: Именно это и надо сделать, программно обращаться к поисковику, осуществить поиск по ключевым словам и сохранить, к примеру, первые  10 страниц.